# how to deal with image upload in flask?

Tags: python, flask, api-design

I am developing an API in flask, and a feature that supports the API, is uploading an avatar image, in order to do this I read the img as base64 and I send the base64 code of the img to the backend.

Whit this the `app.config["MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH"] = 0.1 * 1024 * 1024` is not working and I am sending images too long to the server.

The question is about what best practices can I use in order to enable an endpoint to upload a photo.

Is base64 the right option? should I need to compress the img in the backend?

thanks

Comment: All the information you are looking for is available here:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from [Flask's documenation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/fileuploads/):

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # If the user does not select a file, the browser submits an
        # empty file without a filename.
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('download_file', name=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
```

It should be quite approachable to modify / improve from this.

**Edit after OP's comment**
You can limit the upload size with the suggestions included in the **Improving Uploads** section of the documentation link I have sent.

I also paste the example here for simplicity:

```
from flask import Flask, Request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1000 * 1000
```

In case it doesn't work for you and you want answers on that topic please narrow down the question to it.

In any case I will provide a pointer: did you set app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] right after initializing app (as in the example)?

About not keeping the upload filename you can change it in any way you prefer customizing this section:

```
if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return redirect(url_for('download_file', name=filename))
```

Reading your comment I assume you point to the fact that an API should never trust user input and for this reason in the documentation it is mentioned also the following:

> So what does that secure_filename() function actually do? Now the
> problem is that there is that principle called “never trust user
> input”. This is also true for the filename of an uploaded file. All
> submitted form data can be forged, and filenames can be dangerous. For
> the moment just remember: always use that function to secure a
> filename before storing it directly on the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is a little bit that I am asking, I want to know if is best to encode images because the upload works only with images, I want to know how to limit the file, and the options in the flask documentation doesn't work for base64 for example, another choice can be read the file as a stream, but I want to know another workable experience about this, and I want to avoid write the img in the pod and in that example the are doing and keeping the upload filename, I don't want that too

Comment: My pleasure!
I have edited my answer, please check it.
I am afraid that if you want more precise implementation details then I think that the question you are asking is a bit too broad / subjective.
Please always provide a [mcve] and try to narrow down the scope as much as you can if that is the case.
For example you never mentioned any Kubernetes / pod specific error or requirement in your question.